# When Peach has special offers from Japan, do they also have them to Japan? And if so, how do I find them?

Tags: japan, taiwan, peach-aviation

About five years ago I was in Taiwan and got a cheap flight on a special offer with Peach to Okinawa at a great price.

Now I'm in Taiwan again and I've been receiving special offer emails from Peach all these years. A new one is on now until tomorrow night.

[image: Current special offer pic]
[Current special offer link](https://www.flypeach.com/sp/en/um/specials/sale/sale)

I can see all the offers around Japan, and out of Japan, but not into Japan.

Am I wrong in assuming they have the special offers in both directions? Do I need to look on the Chinese version of their site to see the Taiwan-Japan offers? or is there some way to find if the offers even exist in both directions and how to book them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I wrong in assuming they have the special offers in both directions?

Yes and no. Technically, yes, you are wrong to just assume it, since they can very well sell special fares in only one direction if they wish. However, typically they will sell them in both directions, as is the case here. The full details of which flights are eligible to the discounted fares on which dates are given on the page you linked.

> Do I need to look on the Chinese version of their site to see the Taiwan-Japan offers?

No; the language settings have no effect on fares.

> or is there some way to find if the offers even exist in both directions and how to book them?

Yes, it's all on the page you linked. For example, for flights between TPE and KIX, you have the following.

- Odd-numbered flights (from KIX) on 4-10 May, **from** 2,577 JPY.
- Even-numbered flights (from TPE) on 23-28 April, **from** 2,577 JPY.
- All flights from 8 April to 11 July except on 1-3 May and except the above, **from** 3,977 JPY.

Note that "Osaka - Taipei" without further qualification does not mean just from Osaka to Taipei; it means between Osaka and Taipei in either direction. However, some fares are restricted to specific flights, which can effectively make them available in only one direction (*e.g.*, the even-numbered flights are those that go from Taipei to Osaka, so the fare which is restricted to those flights is effectively restricted to the Taipei to Osaka direction). The full list of flights is available from the timetables [here](https://www.flypeach.com/pc/en/lm/st/schedules).

Finally, this should go without saying but since the number of discounted seats on each flight is limited, a flight even on those dates may not have any left (hence "from").

---

Requested screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I thought I might've missed it due to using my phone at the time, but now I'm on my laptop and there are definitely no flights from Taiwan to Japan when I follow the link. It's possible they serve me different flights because I'm searching from inside Taiwan. Could you please add part of a screengrab showing those flights as you see them?

Comment: @hippietrail Screenshot added.

Comment: Hmm in that case I'm a dummy and I don't know how to read it. To me it looks like those are all from Japan to Taiwan. What am I missing?? Am I supposed to manually look up each flight number in another tab/app?

Comment: Ah, I see. "Osaka - Taipei" does not mean from Osaka to Taipei, it means between Osaka and Taipei in either direction. However, in case the fare mentions that it is restricted to some flights ("MMxxx only"), yes you can just look it up on the timetables [here](https://www.flypeach.com/pc/en/lm/st/schedules).

Comment: Wow! How convoluted, opaque, and user-hostile! I never would've expected it to work in such a way.

Comment: @hippietrail On the bright side, flight-restricted fares are pretty rare, here it's just for two weeks (23-28 April and 4-10 May). Mostly, the fare is for all flights (8 April to 11 July).

Comment: I'm very flexible on cities but not on dates so it's very involved to figure out which flights are both good for me and available. None of them showed up in the several search engines I tried.

Comment: Oh if you edit some of this extra info on how to use the info on their page that wasn't obvious I'll definitely be accepting your answer. Thanks for your help!